# Is using getters and setters the way to pass a message from a parent UIViewController to a method in a UIView class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, getter-setter

I am trying to reorganise an early project by separating code that belongs in a `UIView` from code that belongs in a `UIViewController`. Answers to a popular question ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/2348597)) don’t seem to address what I need to do so let me illustrate my question with two examples.

- Example 1

Here the method `setBackground:zone` changes the background colour of a view to indicate various states in the app. The method *as shown below* currently works and I want to relocate the code to a view where it belongs.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int zone                            = 1; // or 2 or 3;

   self.view                            = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self setBackground:zone];
}

- (void)setBackground:(int)zone {
    switch (zone) {
        case 1:
            self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor orangeColor];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor cyanColor];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

- Example 2

In the code *below* I tried initialising background colour in `CustomView` by using getters and setters to reference the value of `zone` in `ViewController` (appropriate as `ViewControllers` in the original project already get and set `zone` to change background colour).

**CustomView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomView : UIView {
    UIViewController *parent;
    int selectedZone;
}
- (void)setParent:(UIViewController *)parent;
- (int)getSelectedZone;
@end
```

**CustomView.m**

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView
    - (void)setParent:(UIViewController *)theParent {
        parent                          = theParent;
    }

    - (int)getSelectedZone {
        return selectedZone;
    }

    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
        {
        self                            = [super initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        if (self) {

        NSLog(@"selectedZone in CustomView is seen as %i", [self getSelectedZone]);

            int zone                    = [self getSelectedZone];
            [self setBackground:(int) zone];
        }
        return self;
    }

- (void)setBackground:(int)zone {
    switch (zone) {
        case 1:
            self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor orangeColor];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor cyanColor];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.view.backgroundColor   = [UIColor greenColor];
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomView.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController {    
        int selectedZone;
    }

    - (void)setSelectedZone:(int)zone;
    - (int)getSelectedZone;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        int zone                        = 1; // or 2 or 3;    
        [self setSelectedZone:(int)zone];
        NSLog(@"selectedZone in ViewController is now set to %i", [self getSelectedZone]);

        self.view                       = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

        CustomView *cv                  = [[CustomView alloc]init];
        [self.view addSubview:cv];
    }

    - (void)setSelectedZone:(int)zone {
        selectedZone                    = zone;
    }

    - (int)getSelectedZone {
        return selectedZone;
    }
```

I can tell my code *above* does not work because `getSelected:zone` in `CustomView` cannot reference `zone` set by `setSelected:zone` in the `ViewController.` But I don’t understand why.

```
2017-04-05 07:04:26.126 ZoneIndicator[1865:1270743] selectedZone in ViewController is now set to 1 
2017-04-05 07:04:26.126 ZoneIndicator[1865:1270743] selectedZone in CustomView is seen as 0
```

But [an article found here](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) has even made me question whether using getters and setters is the best approach - especially this:

> The biggest danger here is that by asking for data from an object, you
>   are only getting data. You’re not getting an object—not in the large
>   sense. Even if the thing you received from a query is an object
>   structurally (e.g., a String) it is no longer an object semantically.
>   It no longer has any association with its owner object. Just because
>   you got a string whose contents was “RED”, you can’t ask the string
>   what that means. Is it the owners last name? The color of the car? The
>   current condition of the tachometer? An object knows these things,
>   data does not.

So how do I pass the message from a parent UIViewController to a method in a UIView class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly okay for a vc to set it's view's properties.  Here's annotated code for your first example...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // no need to do this, the UIViewController this inherits from creates the view
    // int zone                            = 1; // or 2 or 3;
    //self.view                            = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    [self setBackgroundColorForZone:zone];
}

// improved naming for clarity
- (void) setBackgroundColorForZone:(NSInteger)zone {
    // fine as you have it
    switch //...
    // ...
}
```

If you have some better reason to develop a custom `UIView` subclass to be that view controller's view, that's okay, too.  You can either replace your view with the custom instance or cover the default view with a child that has the same frame.  But it's unwise to give a view a pointer to it's view controller (and even more unwise to call this pointer "parent")

So for your second example, the custom view class should be substantially simplified...

```
@interface CustomView : UIView {
    // commented out bad stuff
    // UIViewController *parent;
    // this isn't needed either
    //int selectedZone;
}
// these aren't needed either
//- (void)setParent:(UIViewController *)parent;
//- (int)getSelectedZone;

// just this
- (void)setBackgroundColorForZone:(NSInteger)zone;

@end
```

And the implementation can have the same method that was in your first example.  It takes a zone integer and set's `self.backgroundColor` (instead of `self.view.backgroundColor`).

The view controller that manages this view can be simplified now to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int zone                        = 1; // or 2 or 3; 
    // don't need this   
    //[self setSelectedZone:(int)zone];
    //NSLog(@"selectedZone in ViewController is now set to %i", [self getSelectedZone]);

    // never need this
    //self.view                       = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    // notice the change to init with frame
    CustomView *cv                  = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [cv setBackgroundColorForZone:zone];
    [self.view addSubview:cv];
}

// don't need any of this
//- (void)setSelectedZone:(int)zone {
//    selectedZone                    = zone;
//}

//- (int)getSelectedZone {
//    return selectedZone;
//}
```

Comment: danh, thanks for your detailed explanation. This is the perfect simple solution I was missing in the project. I'll have to think about "unwise to give a view a pointer to it's view controller (and even more unwise to call this pointer "parent")".

Comment: :-) happy to help.  The naming point is that "parent" is used by UIView to refer to the view within which it appears, not the view controller that manages it.  The reason it's unwise to keep the pointer at all is more about design tradition, the strong ownership and information flow goes *from* the view controller *to* the views, not the other way around.  Views sometimes do need to communicate backwards on that chain, and a common approach for that is "delegation".